# IMPORTXML XPath_Query for Google Sheets

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, xquery

I'm using GoogleSheet's `IMPORTXML` function to retrieve data for each calendar date one year earlier or the closest year-ago date where data are available.

This is a sample of the data ([full data source is here](http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202017)):

```
 <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6794)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-06T22:05:38Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6794)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6794</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-02-24T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.4</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.52</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.65</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.8</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.12</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.38</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.8</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.12</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.31</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.69</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.95</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.95</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <id>http://data.treasury.gov/Feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6795)</id>
    <title type="text"></title>
    <updated>2018-02-06T22:05:38Z</updated>
    <author>
      <name />
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" href="DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData(6795)" />
    <category term="TreasuryDataWarehouseModel.DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateDatum" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6795</d:Id>
        <d:NEW_DATE m:type="Edm.DateTime">2017-02-27T00:00:00</d:NEW_DATE>
        <d:BC_1MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.44</d:BC_1MONTH>
        <d:BC_3MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.5</d:BC_3MONTH>
        <d:BC_6MONTH m:type="Edm.Double">0.68</d:BC_6MONTH>
        <d:BC_1YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">0.81</d:BC_1YEAR>
        <d:BC_2YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.2</d:BC_2YEAR>
        <d:BC_3YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.46</d:BC_3YEAR>
        <d:BC_5YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">1.87</d:BC_5YEAR>
        <d:BC_7YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.18</d:BC_7YEAR>
        <d:BC_10YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.36</d:BC_10YEAR>
        <d:BC_20YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.72</d:BC_20YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEAR m:type="Edm.Double">2.98</d:BC_30YEAR>
        <d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY m:type="Edm.Double">2.98</d:BC_30YEARDISPLAY>
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
```

This is the XPath query I'm currently using to retrieve data for 2017 Feb 27:

```
//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE'][text() = '2017-02-27T00:00:00']/..
```

This is the result that displays:

```
6795    2017-02-27T00:00:00 0.44    0.5 0.68    0.81    1.2 1.46    1.87    2.18    2.36    2.72    2.98    2.98
```

Is there a way to:

1. Retrieve all data displayed except the "d:Id" element ("6795" above)
   and
2. If searching for a date for which there are no data (e.g. 2017
   Feb 25 will result in a "#N/A" error since the query would return nothing for the missing date), the query will default to the next available forward date (e.g. 2017 Feb 27)?

I'm avoiding using the IF function in order to make fewer `IMPORTXML` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Google Sheets (GS) seems to be compatible with only XPath 1.0 (its [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) and product forum pages [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Pm0fJYi_WRM) and [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/Uq8-J7yN_Ec) don't confirm or clarify which version(s) is supported as of this date), alternative approaches such as XPath 2.0 `IF-THEN-ELSE` statements [cannot be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260455/how-to-write-an-if-else-statement-for-xpath-with-multiple-cases).  Instead, the source XML data sought can be filtered using GS native functions.

**QUESTION 1**

Per @Tanaike's proposed solution, retrieving all children nodes of an element, save one, can be accomplished using the XPath "not" command, i.e. `!`, as applied below to the parent element of "NEW_DATE" and leaving out the child element "Id".  `TRANSPOSE` is used to display it in columnar form.  (A1 is the cell containing the source XML URL in the question.)

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE'][text() = '2017-02-25T00:00:00']/../*[local-name()!='Id']"))
```

**QUESTION 2**

To search for a specific date one year ago and, in case data for that date are missing, to retrieve the closest forward date will require nested GS functions to first retrieve the "NEW_DATE" data with the above formula, next to reverse its order using `SORT` and to `MATCH` the closest available date.  The `INDEX` function is then used on the reverse-sorted element to select the appropriate date.  The `CONCATENATE`, `TEXT` and `TODAY` functions are used just to set the year-ago date in a format compatible with the XML data.  The formula is below.

`=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1,CONCATENATE("//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE'][text() = '",INDEX(SORT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE']"),1,FALSE),MATCH(CONCATENATE(TEXT(TODAY()-365,"YYYY-MM-DD"),"T00:00:00"),SORT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE']"),1,FALSE),-1)),"']/../*[local-name()! = 'Id']")))`

Answer (score 2):

How about this answer?

### For your 1st question

#### Sample :

```
=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE'][text() = '2017-02-27T00:00:00']/../*[local-name()!='Id']"))
```

- "A1" is the URL of `http://data.treasury.gov/feed.svc/DailyTreasuryYieldCurveRateData?$filter=year(NEW_DATE)%20eq%202017`.
- For `//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE'][text() = '2017-02-27T00:00:00']/..`, values except for `<d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">6795</d:Id>` were retrieved.
- The result is transposed, because the values are outputted to rows.

#### Result :

[image]

### For your 2nd question

When `=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE'][text() = '2017-02-25T00:00:00']/../*[local-name()!='Id']"))` is used, the result of `#N/A` is retrieved.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: The solution to the first problem works as expected.  Thanks.  The second problem should retrieve the next available date; so instead of a result of '#N/A' when querying for '2017-02-25T00:00:00', the query should seek the next available date, i.e. '2017-02-27T00:00:00'.  Is this possible?

Comment: @Catalyx I'm sorry for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. For your 2nd question, I think that it may be difficult to achieve it using functions. You can retrieve the list of date using ``=ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE']"))``. If those data can be parsed as date, it may take a step nearer take a step closer. I think that google apps script may be suitable for this situation. I'm really sorry I couldn't answer for your one of 2 questions.

Comment: I found a solution using `INDEX`, `SORT` and `MATCH` functions.  Yes, it required a few nested functions.  I'll later post that solution.

Maybe using `MIN`, `MAX` and `POSITION` could have helped.  I'm not expert with XPath and not sure if Google Sheets supports XPath 2.0, which could have made it easier with an `IF-THEN-ELSE` statement.   Thanks.

Comment: @Catalyx Thank you for your additional information. I'm glad your problem was solved. I would like to wait for your post and study from your post. Thank you, too.

Comment: This is a shortened version of my formula:  `=TRANSPOSE(IMPORTXML(A1,CONCATENATE("//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE'][text() = '",INDEX(SORT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE']"),1,FALSE),MATCH(CONCATENATE(TEXT(TODAY()-365,"YYYY-MM-DD"),"T00:00:00'"),SORT(IMPORTXML(A1, "//*[local-name() = 'NEW_DATE']"),1,FALSE),-1)),"']/../*[local-name()! = 'Id']")))`.  Not very elegant but works as intended.  I hope this helps, too.  Thanks.

Comment: @Catalyx Thank you for your additional information. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.