# Google Sheets IMPORTXML: Xpath not working (document node does provide data)

Tags: api, xpath, import, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets, I am trying to retrieve text passages from the [Perseus Scaife Library](https://scaife.perseus.org/reader/urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0527.tlg001.opp-grc2:1.1/), which has a working API. 
When I query for the document node 
(`=importxml("https://scaife-cts.perseus.org/api/cts?request=GetPassage&urn=urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0527.tlg001.opp-grc2:1.1","/")`)
 I get all the data, including the URNs etc. However, any other `xpath_query` gives an error.

I know that Google Sheets can access the data, but I would like to be able to select only one node (`//p`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve the text in passage. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

```
=importxml(A1, "//*[local-name()='passage']")
```

#### Result :

[image]

#### Note :

- `https://scaife-cts.perseus.org/api/cts?request=GetPassage&urn=urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0527.tlg001.opp-grc2:1.1` is converted by URL encode and put to "A1".

  - Converted URL is `https://scaife-cts.perseus.org/api/cts?request=GetPassage&urn=urn%3acts%3agreekLit%3atlg0527%2etlg001%2eopp%2dgrc2%3a1%2e1`.

#### Reference :

- [local-name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name)

If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Comment: That was indeed what I wanted, thank you! However, some passages include one or more notes, placed in `note` within `p` ([example](https://scaife-cts.perseus.org/api/cts?request=GetPassage&urn=urn:cts:greekLit:tlg0527.tlg018.1st1K-grc1:12.16)). Is there some way to exclude them? I already tried `"//*[local-name()='p']/../*[local-name()!='note']"`, based on [your answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48800941/7179031), but it elides any data past the `note`-node. With `'paragraph'` instead of `'p'` it only gives the initial URN.

Comment: @Jopie I read your comment. But I couldn't understand your current situation from your comment. So can you post it with the detail information as a new question? By this, many users including me can think of your solution. I would like to clearly understand what you want. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.